# How to identify device and its IP on network by MAC on Ubuntu 10.04+?

Tags: ip, mac, network-attached-storage, scripting, ethernet

I have a NAS (LinkStation Mini). Its windows software identifies it correctly. I want to identify device and its IP and mount the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull up the Window's ARP table with "arp -a" (without the quotes) the at command prompt, since it is already communicating with the device based upon your description. It's ARP table should contain the device's MAC-to-IP mapping for its communication.

Comment: Hi. I am Ubuntu. Does my device publish ARP packets ? How do i know ? When i type rarp it says not supported on this kernel.

Comment: "Its windows software identifies it correctly." Go to the Windows system and perform the described steps to obtain the currently assigned IP or assign the device a static IP when you can access it.